# webpack hangs at on "95% emit" / "95% emitting"

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, webpack, webpack-2

[This is my production webpack config](http://hastebin.com/oligitafov.cpp). The two quotes in the title refer to webpack2 and webpack respectively. Both hang for me with a similar error.

This is my command to trigger the build

`set NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config config/webpack.config.prod.js --progress --display-error-details`

What am I missing?

Here is the output after running `npm run pack` which correlates to my production webpack build:

```
$ npm run pack

> somedir@ pack C:\somedir
> set NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config config/webpack.config.prod.js --progress --display-error-details
                           95% emitting
```

Comment: The error message would be helpful.

Comment: There is no error message, webpack is hanging on "95% emitting" :,)

Comment: Updated my answer with some console output

Comment: Define "hang"? How long did you leave it for? How big is the output file you're expecting? Are you using SourceMaps? Are you using a minifier like Uglify?

Comment: Try commenting directives

Comment: @loganfsmyth i've let it run for 5 minutes, 30 minutes, 45 minutes, and now 2 hours (since i posted the question). the output can be a simple console.log to a small react component rendering to the dom. both instances hang. yes i'm using uglify and `devtool: 'source-map'`, although i've removed both from my config (stripped it down to just the entry point). i'm making some progress now..

Comment: i've fixed it. it looks like having a colon in the `output.path` throws it off. `output.path: './build'` is fine, `output.path: '/build/this:is:not:okay/` is not okay

Comment: This would be a good situation to run node 6.3 --inspect flag and run a heap snapshot in dev tools.

Comment: of course it makes sense since they are reserved characters.. but still, derp. thanks loganfsmyth and @martriay for your suggestion however!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I figured this out. It turns out I was including [reserved characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions) in my output path. I've since [opened an issue on github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2908).

> When using an invalid or reserved character in the output.path webpack
>   will hang with no output. Running with the --progress flag will show
>   that it's hanging on 95% emit(ting) (suffix depending on webpack
>   version).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, to figure this out as well I ran `node --inspect node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js` and then opened output URL in chrome that allowed me to debug code. I then saw it got stuck in `mkdirp` so added a `console.log` in the function in that node module to see what path was triggering the infinite loop. The issue for me was a path like `c:\path\to\output\c:\source\file` and threw an error due to the colon.

Comment: Same issue here, but my root cause was a SASS file that triggered a missing variable error, which webpack processed as JS (`throw new Error`) and included it as a file. Which on Windows has an absolute source file path, including the `:` character which triggered the mkdirP function infinite loop.

Comment: holy moly what a ride

Answer (score 4):

In my case (Windows environment and laravel-mix) there weren't any incorrect characters in the path, since even a dead simple configuration didn't work. It was just webpack (webpack@3.12.0) doing something stupid of his own and the problem has been solved using `publicPath` option like this:

```
mix.options({
    publicPath: ('./')
});
```

which according to the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/):

> allows you to specify the base path for all the assets within your application

Alternatively you can use:

```
mix.setPublicPath('./');
```

Answer (score 2):

I use laravel-mix as a **standalone**.
This is my my config:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('./')
   .js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css');
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

#### I fixed by upgrading to `webpack@4.41.2`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was trying to use Angular 4, Webpack 3, AOT and lazy loading.
Using `@ngtools/webpack` and [AotPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack) made it freeze at 95%.

What fixed was:
 1). Install `node-sass` with `npm install node-sass --no-bin-links`, because it was not installed automatically with `sass-loader`.
 2). Adding these loaders for the SCSS/CSS files (even inside node modules):

```
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                'css-loader'
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                'raw-loader',
                'sass-loader'
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

solved ist by me.

Answer (score 1):

This error also occurs if you have invalid import.
Import referring from other files which is not getting compiled.

Answer (score 1):

This will also happen if you use `indexTransform` property and the function is throwing an error. To handle this you can wrap your function in a try/catch;

```
module.exports = (targetOptions, indexHtml) => {
  try {
    ...
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1) // Kills webpack
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running `ng build` and `node --inspect node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js` should give output of the problem paths

Answer (score 0):

I have missclick when copy index.html (cut this file from angular folder). After copy them back problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Angular when I was setting up a project. The problem was that I wrongly placed the index.html file out of `./src` folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was something with the directory defined in output.path. After deleting it's content (different folders with different bundles) everything was working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I was missing a closing `>` on a `<div>`.

Webpack (mix) would hang instead of just failing to compile and I'm not sure why.
Hopefully, this can save someone a few hours of going down the wrong rabbit hole.