# CopyWebpackPlugin rename with test and template options

Tags: regex, webpack

Using CopyWebpackPlugin, I'm trying to copy a file with a specific version in the name (e.g. "calcitemaps-arcgis-support-v0.9.js", "otherlibaray-v0.9.js") to my output directory, but stripping the version ("-v0.9) from the filename.

Using the test and toType options, I would think that

```
{
   from: './node_modules/calcite-maps/dist/js/dojo/*0.9*',
   to: './calcite/[1].[ext]',
   toType: 'template',
   flatten: true,
   test: /(.*(?=-))\.js/
  }
```

should work, but all I'm getting in my destination directory is a file called [1].js.

I also tried `/.*(?=-)\.js/`, `/(.*(?=-))/`, and `/.*(?=-)/`, none of them worked...

RegEx is obviously not my strong suit here - can anyone help?

Comment: After hyphen `-` I see there is `v0.9` string as well. Try changing your regex to this `/(.*(?=-))-v0\.9\.js/` in case you want to only match files having `v0.9` before `.js` or if you want to match any version, generalize the version regex like this ``/(.*(?=-))-v\d+(\.\d+)*\.js/``

Comment: The directory has all versions in it, and I want to target a specific version, based on an environment variable - so my from value is actually `./node_modules/calcite-maps/dist/js/dojo/*${process.env.VERSION_TO_TARGET}*`.  But for some reason the expression you suggested just makes webpack hang and the build never finishes....is the idea in order to use templates, you need at minimum capture groups?

Comment: I don't think capture groups should be making it hang, but just in case it is, then you can make it a non-grouping pattern by appending `?:` before starting `(` and change your regex to `(?:.*(?=-))-v\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.js`

Comment: okay - your regex is working, but webpack is getting hung up on the template.  Looking at the debug, it shows - `writing '../../../calcite/H:\www\eonearth\node_modules\calcite-maps\dist\js\dojo\calcitemaps.js' to compilation assets from 'H:\www\eonearth\node_modules\calcite-maps\dist\js\dojo\calcitemaps-v0.9.js'` - I can start a new thread to address this issue...

Comment: Sorry I've never used webpack tool, so not sure what is causing it to hang. But some googling for `webpack tool hangs` showed me decent results pointing to some other issues. [Check this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8234) and [even this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085686/webpack-hangs-at-on-95-emit-95-emitting) May be try googling a bit and it might give you some helpful pointers.